# Cant add coreGraphics to my project

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics

i've created a new project where i need to use the coreGraphics library, but when i search there is no library called that. Is it possible that i've deleted the coreGraphics library? if yes, how is it possible to add it to xcode again.

what i've done is

```
build settings->link binary with libraries-> search "coregraphics"
```

I'm using the xcode 6 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on Xcode6 Beta 6 and did this steps:
1) Go to Build settings (make sure that you selected the target on the left side, not the project
2) On the right side, go to Link Binary with libraries
3) Click the add button
4) Search for core graphics, it is there

Wish it helps!